# Problem with OMRON GV3M-31BR

Tags: solid-state-relay, optical

[image][image: Circuit mentioned]

Hi,
I was using OMRON GV3m-31BR to switch 24VDC at 2A(Max) and the 24VDC Switching signal was then used to control the relay by using the voltage divider as shown. The is switching as normal but as the relay is operated continuously for about 5 days it was getting brown near pin 4. What could be the probable reasons?

Comment: Can you please add a photo to illustrate your issue?

Comment: From the datasheet, it seems pin 5 should be grounded. What is 24VDC_CTRL?

Comment: I used pin 6 as 24V input and PIN 5 as 24V output.

Comment: Likely you provided no freewheel diode across the relay coil and therefore the optocoupler is now toasted.

Comment: Also... is the primary and secondary sharing a common ground, as it looks like in the picture? In that case what's the purpose of the optocoupler, to act as a source of problems, or...?

Comment: I was trying to use   the Opto Mosfet  as a switch to turn the power to a part on my PCB

Comment: Then why not use a MOSFET?

Answer (score 0):

You are starving the input LED for current. It it specified at 5mA in connection 'C'.

You're giving it more like 1/10 of that. If it doesn't turn on fully, it can get hot and damage itself. If you're switching an inductive load you also should have a free-wheeling diode as Lundin mentions.

Some better resistors-

R105 = 3.3kΩ 0.25W

R106 = 1kΩ

R101 = 0Ω (or leave it at 100Ω)